# TypeError: group_by_retval() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'grouper_func'

Tags: python, python-3.5

guys below is my code for dictionary generating:

```
import collections
from typing import Callable

def group_by_retval(*args, grouper_func: Callable[[], None]):
    my_list = []
    for elem in args:
        my_tr = grouper_func(elem)
        my_list.append([my_tr,elem])
    my_tuple = tuple(tuple(elem) for elem in my_list)
    my_diction = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for k,v in my_tuple:
        my_diction[k].append(v)
    return my_diction
```

I have read from python official documentation that I can announce callable function after the *args. as above. However, when I run simple example like below I got an error. Can someone please help me to solve this issue. Thank you for reading:

```
l = ["ab", 12, "cd", "d", 3]


print(group_by_retval(l, lambda x: isinstance(x, str)))
```

Comment: Post full error traceback

Comment: `group_by_retval(l, grouper_func=lambda x: isinstance(x, str))`

Comment: @kvorobiev Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testm.py", line 20, in <module>
    print(group_by_retval(l, lambda x: isinstance(x, str)))
TypeError: group_by_retval() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'grouper_func'

Comment: @vaultah What do you mean "must be provided by name"?

Comment: @vaultah thanks. Maybe you can give me an idea. How can I do that without providing a name? Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, after `*arg` (arbitrary arguments list) you could use only [keyword arguments](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists):

```
group_by_retval(l, grouper_func=lambda x: isinstance(x, str))
```

to do it without providing a name you could swap arguments:

```
def group_by_retval(grouper_func: Callable[[], None], *args):
...

print(group_by_retval(lambda x: isinstance(x, str), l))
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {False: [['ab', 12, 'cd', 'd', 3]]})
```

But in fact, you just do not need to use arbitrary arguments list, because your first argument is a `list`. Right solution

```
def group_by_retval(args, grouper_func: Callable[[], None]):
...
print(group_by_retval(l, lambda x: isinstance(x, str)))
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {False: [12, 3], True: ['ab', 'cd', 'd']})
```